# Changing an image using Python Imaging library

Tags: python, image

I am trying to make a slot machine using images to display the roll of the slot machine. I get an error 
    `TclError: image "3.bmp" doesn't exist`

But I have clearly defined every image that I am using for the machine. (I would have added all of them but for the sake of readability I added 2-5. 1, 2, and, 3 are all the same and 4-9 are the same)

`image2 = Image.open('2.bmp')`
`photo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image2)`
`label2 = Label(image=photo2)`
`label2.image = photo2`
`label2.grid(row=0, column=1)`

`image3 = Image.open('3.bmp')`
`photo3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image3)`
`label3 = Label(image=photo3)`
`label3.image = photo3`
`label3.grid(row=0, column=2)`

`image4 = Image.open('4.bmp')`
`photo4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image4)`

`image5 = Image.open('5.bmp')`
`photo5 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image5)`

the function I use to change the image is also the function to roll the machine.

> `def spin():
>       with open ('highscore.txt','r+b') as H:
>           money = H.read().strip()
>           if money == '' or money == "0":
>               money = 10
>           else:
>               money = int(money)
>           if money <=1:
>               tkMessageBox.showinfo('You are broke!','You have no money to your name! You can not spin anymore.')
>               slots.destroy()
>           money -= 1
>       with open("highscore.txt", "wb") as H:
>           H.write(str(money))
>       for number in range(0,3):
>           slot_roll.append(random.randint(1,9))
>       label1.config(image=img_lib[slot_roll[0]])
>       label2.config(image=img_lib[slot_roll[1]])
>       label3.config(image=img_lib[slot_roll[2]])`

img_lib is a dictionary of images used to find the name of the file:

> 'img_lib={1:'1.png',2:'2.bmp',3:'3.bmp',4:'4.bmp',5:'5.bmp',6:'6.bmp',7:'7.jpg',8:'8.bmp',9:'9.png'}'

Comment: could you post the error log exactly. If you are saying the above error is the only error, then there is something wrong wit either you mentioning the path to 3.bmp wrongly

Comment: A common problem with images and `Tkinter` is that just because you specify something like `Label(image=photo3)` doesn't mean that `photo3` (or the `image3` it's based on) won't be garbage-collected if `image3` and/or `photo3` are local variables. The common workaround it to attach them as attributes to some widget with a longer lifespan. You haven't shown enough code for me to be more specific or even tell for sure if that is what the problem you're having however.